# Strict searching against two different files

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I have two questions regarding the following code:

```
import subprocess

macSource1 = (r"\\Server\path\name\here\dhcp-dump.txt")
macSource2 = (r"\\Server\path\name\here\dhcp-dump-ops.txt")

with open (r"specific-pcs.txt") as file:
    line = []
    for line in file:
        pcName = line.strip().upper()
        with open (macSource1) as source1, open (macSource2) as source2:
            items = []
            for items in source1:
                if pcName in items:
                    items_split = items.rstrip("\n").split('\t')
                    ip = items_split[0]
                    mac = items_split[4]
                    mac2 = ':'.join(s.encode('hex') for s in mac.decode('hex')).lower()  # Puts the :'s between the pairs.
                    print mac2
                    print pcName
                    print ip
```

Firstly, as you can see, the script is searching for the contents of "specific-pcs.txt" against the contents of macSource1 to get various details. How do I get it to search against BOTH macSource1 & 2 (as the details could be in either file)??

And secondly, I need to have a stricter matching process as at the moment a machine called 'itroom02' will not only find it's own details, but also provide the details for another machine called '2nd-itroom02'. How would I get that?

Many thanks for your assistance in advance!
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should restructure it a bit more like this:

```
macSources = [ r"\\Server\path\name\here\dhcp-dump.txt",
               r"\\Server\path\name\here\dhcp-dump-ops.txt" ]

with open (r"specific-pcs.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        # ....
        for target in macSources:
            with open (target) as source:
                for items in source:
                   # ....
```

There's no need to do e.g. `line = []` immediately before you do `for line in ...:`.

As far as the "stricter matching" goes, since you don't give examples of the format of your files, I can only guess - but you might want to try something like `if items_split[1] == pcName:` after you've done the split, instead of the `if pcName in items:` before you split (assuming the name is in the second column - adjust accordingly if not).

Comment: Thanks @twalberg, I love the simple fix's like your example - works perfectly.

Sorry, yes the format of the txt files is basically just a tab deliminated list exported from the dhcp server, so a column of ip addresses, then pc names, mac addresses and a few other bits of rubbish.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, the pc name on the txt file is the FQDN, so pcName.domain, so a simple item = pcName probably won't work...

Comment: In that case, perhaps `items_split[1].startswith(pcName + '.')` might be a suitable alternative...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg, you've brilliantly answered both my questions.